# Wifi completely disappeared after attempting to install realtech drivers

Tags: networking, drivers

My wifi adapter wasn't working properly: it would constantly disconnect and sometimes show password prompt even though the correct password was already entered (I just had to press enter). The solution everyone was mentioning was to install the driver from this GitHub account: https://github.com/lwfinger (I installed /rtw89)

Here's what I did (following the readme tutorial):

> git clone, cd, make

> sudo make install

outputs:

```
/rtw89$ sudo make install

[sudo] password for alex:

make -C /lib/modules/5.19.0-31-generic/build M-/home/alex/rtw89 nodules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.19.0-31-generic'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel 

    The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.2.0-3ubuntu1) 12.2.0

    You are using: gcc (Ubuntu 12.2.0-3ubuntu1) 12.2.0 make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.19.0-31-generic'

Install rtw89 SUCCESS
```

> restart the computer

Then wifi completely disappeared from settings and the pop-up menu in the corner. `sudo lshw -C network` prints `network UNCLAIMED` for the wireless network adapter (ethernet is fine)

I tried `sudo make uninstall` but it didn't change anything

How can I go back to how it was before until I replace this adapter?

---

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, no dual boot. Desktop

Comment: @guiverc edited. don't know how to find which stack it is but kernel version is 5.19.0-31-generic

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by Secure Boot.

At first I tried to use `sudo make sign-install` (https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89#installation-with-module-signing-for-secureboot) but I couldn't figure out what to do in the MOK menu, so I just disabled secure boot and it fixed the problem.